# Access Denied when deploying ASP.net 5

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.net 5 website to my local service fabric dev cluster but get an Access Denied exception on every deploy. I know that the problem is with the web service because when I remove it from the deployment my other service is deployed without any error

This exception looks like it is trying to delete a file, but which one and why wouldn't it have access?

```
6>. 'E:\Github\Flow.Server\Flow.Server.Fabric\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1' -ApplicationPackagePath 'E:\Github\Flow.Server\Flow.Server.Fabric\pkg\Debug' -PublishProfileFile 'E:\Github\Flow.Server\Flow.Server.Fabric\PublishProfiles\Local.xml' -DeployOnly:$true -UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade $false -OverrideUpgradeBehavior 'None' -OverwriteBehavior 'Always' -ErrorAction Stop
6>Message        : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
6>Data           : {}
6>InnerException :  
6>TargetSite     : Void RunInMTA(System.Action)
6>StackTrace     :    at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.RunInMTA(Action action)
6>                    at System.Fabric.Common.FabricDirectory.Delete(String path, Boolean recursive, Boolean 
6>                 deleteReadOnlyFiles)
6>                    at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ApplicationCmdletBase.TestApplicationPackage(String 
6>                 applicationPackagePath, Hashtable applicationParameters, String imageStoreConnectionString)
6>                    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
6>HelpLink       : 
6>Source         : System.Fabric
6>HResult        : -2147024891
```

Here is my ApplicationManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="Flow.Server.FabricType" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
   <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="Silo_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
   </Parameters>
   <ServiceManifestImport>
      <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="Flow.Server.Fabric.WebApi" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
   </ServiceManifestImport>
   <ServiceManifestImport>
      <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="Flow.Server.Fabric.SiloPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
      <ConfigOverrides />
   </ServiceManifestImport>
   <DefaultServices>
      <Service Name="Flow.Server.Fabric.WebApiService">
         <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="Flow.Server.Fabric.WebApiType">
            <SingletonPartition />
         </StatelessService>
      </Service>
      <Service Name="Flow.Server.Fabric.Silo">
         <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="Flow.Server.Fabric.SiloType" InstanceCount="[Silo_InstanceCount]">
            <SingletonPartition />
         </StatelessService>
      </Service>
   </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

And here is the ServiceManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="Flow.Server.Fabric.WebApi" Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
   <ServiceTypes>
      <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="Flow.Server.Fabric.WebApiType">
         <Extensions>
            <Extension Name="__GeneratedServiceType__">
               <GeneratedNames xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
                  <DefaultService Name="Flow.Server.Fabric.WebApiService" />
                  <ServiceEndpoint Name="Flow.Server.Fabric.WebApiTypeEndpoint" />
               </GeneratedNames>
            </Extension>
         </Extensions>
      </StatelessServiceType>
   </ServiceTypes>
   <CodePackage Name="C" Version="1.0.0">
      <EntryPoint>
         <ExeHost>
            <Program>approot\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe</Program>
            <Arguments>--appbase approot\src\Flow.Server.Fabric.WebApi Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener</Arguments>
            <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
            <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="5" FileMaxSizeInKb="2048" />
         </ExeHost>
      </EntryPoint>
   </CodePackage>
   <Resources>
      <Endpoints>
         <Endpoint Name="Flow.Server.Fabric.WebApiTypeEndpoint" Protocol="http" Type="Input" />
      </Endpoints>
   </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

Comment: Just to make sure we clear out the basic problems: Are you running multiple instances of VS? Are you running your VS with admin rights? Do you have unrestricted Execution Policy for your SF? And finally, do you have another instance in debug mode or attached to the debugger?

Comment: @Dorival I'm running a single instance of VS as admin. I have unrestricted execution policy and no debugger attached. I have tried restarting the pc and have the same problem